# How to get previous calculated results of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I have the following scenario that I need help with.

The rule is, sum of amount can not be greater than 7 for **any** 10 minutes (if greater the amount replace with zero). Can this be done using analytic functions?

Here's the example data and the expectied result.

```
with test_data as
   (         select 1 id , 0.2 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 18:42','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 2 id , 0.4 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 18:58','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 3 id , 3.0 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 18:59','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 4 id , 0.2 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 5 id , 0.2 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:01','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 6 id , 0.4 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:02','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 7 id , 2.6 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:04','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 8 id , 0.2 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:05','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 9 id , 11.2 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:06','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 10 id , 10.8 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:08','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 11 id , 11.4 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:09','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 12 id , 6.8 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:18','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 13 id , 1.8 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:19','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 14 id , 1.6 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:21','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   union all select 15 id , 11.4 amount,to_date('01.01.2010 19:23','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt from dual
   )
   select
     *
    from
     test_data
```

Expected result is:

```
id   amount   dt                calculated_amount
1    0.2      1.1.2010 18:42    0.2
2    0.4      1.1.2010 18:58    0.4
3    3        1.1.2010 18:59    3
4    0.2      1.1.2010 19:00    0.2
5    0.2      1.1.2010 19:01    0.2
6    0.4      1.1.2010 19:02    0.4
7    2.6      1.1.2010 19:04    2.6
8    0.2      1.1.2010 19:05    0.2
9    11.2     1.1.2010 19:06    0
10   10.8     1.1.2010 19:08    0
11   11.4     1.1.2010 19:09    0.4
12   6.8      1.1.2010 19:18    6.6
13   1.8      1.1.2010 19:19    0
14   1.6      1.1.2010 19:21    0.4
15   11.4     1.1.2010 19:23    0
```

for id = 1 time 18:42 add 10 minutes to this time and you find 18:52. But there is no rows smaller than 18:52, so go on.
For id = 2 time 18:58 add 10 minutes and you find 19:08. you can select and sum amount between 18:58 and 19:08. The total amount is 29. Our rule is broken, so we start to calculate sum of id between 2 and 10 row by row. When you achieved total is grater than 7, you can put zero. (0.4+3+0.2+0.2+0.4+2.6+0.2 = 7 so id =9 and 10 must be zero). And we must use this calculation for all rows with calculated rows before.
For id = 3 time 18:59 add 10 minutes and you find 19:09. This time, we sum calculated values before (3+0.2+0.2+0.4+2.6+0.2+0+0 = 6.6 ) so, new calculated value is 7-6.6 = 0.4 (if amount greater than the difference)

you can see steps in this [link](http://prntscr.com/6cknn7)

Comment: How to you get 0.4 for ID 11, for example? The sum of the 10 minute period up to that ID is 40. And for ID 12 it's 29. Why aren't all the calculated amounts after ID 8 all zero? Please edit the question to explain your logic in more detail. And is your 10-minute window covering up to each row, or either side of it?

Comment: Thanks your interest. I added some explanation. I hope this helps.

Comment: If you're looking at the 10 minute period *from* ID 2, the sum is 29, so why are you showing 0.4 instead of zero for that ID?

Comment: I have added new comment for id = 3, for example.

Comment: I think you're trying too hard to simplify the problem, or obfuscate it, but in hiding detail you've actually made it difficult to understand the problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: If the sum between 18:58 and 19:08 is 29 (sum of IDs 2 to 10), why is the sum between 18:59 and 19:09 only 6.6, not 18 (sum of IDs 3 to 11, with 9 and 10 set to zero)? Why is ID 8's 10.8 amount included in the first case, but ID 11's 11.4 amount is not included in the second case? And why are you subtracting from seven now?

Comment: Because we calculate the rows between 3 and 10 on previous step. We must use these calculated values in next steps.

Comment: @AlexPoole Also you advice another method or logic to solve the problem using the rule.

Comment: @Serkkan - yes, I get that the previous step changes 9 and 10 to zero. But on the iteration for ID 3, I don't get why you ignore the value of ID 11, which is 11.4. (3+0.2+0.2+0.4+2.6+0.2+0+0+11.4 = 18). You aren't being consistent. In the previous step you included the ID 10 value when calculating the total to be 29. And in your link, for the 9th iteration you're including the value for ID 12.

Comment: @Serkkan - I've come up with some logic that gets the result you wanted; it wasn't clear that you were making some of the changes based on the running total one row behind, which is where the 7-sum part comes in too. This would have been much easier if you'd explained the logic more clearly. But, so far I've only come up with a procedural solution. Maybe this will help someone else figure out a plain SQL approach.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't *entirely* given up on the possibility that this might be achievable in plain SQL, possibly via the model clause; but in the meantime here's a PL/SQL solution that seems to adhere to what I *think* the rules are supposed to be. It gets the right answer, anyway...

```
create type type42 as object (id number, amount number, dt date,
  calculated_amount number)
/

create type tab42 as table of type42
/

create function f42 return tab42 pipelined as
  l_tab tab42;
  l_sum number;
  l_last_sum number;
begin
  -- load the starting state into a collection; calculated amount is
  -- initially just the original amount
  select type42(id, amount, dt, amount)
  bulk collect into l_tab
  from test_data;

  -- iterate over the collection row by row, each time adjusting the
  -- following 10-minute's worth of rows. As the collection is being
  -- updated, each iteration sees the changes from earlier ones
  for i in 1..l_tab.count loop
    l_sum := 0;
    l_last_sum := 0;

    <<inner_loop>>
    -- look at all rows later than the current one
    for j in i..l_tab.count loop
      -- but we're only interested in the 10 minute period after the
      -- starting row for this iteration (inclusive; so 19:08:00 looks
      -- at rows up to 19:18:00, not 19:17:59), so exit if later
      if l_tab(j).dt > l_tab(i).dt + interval '10' minute then
        -- row is more than 10 minutes ahead, so stop this iteration
        exit inner_loop;
      end if;

      -- adjust the running total based on this row's calculated amount
      -- which may have been changed by previous iterations
      l_sum := l_sum + l_tab(j).calculated_amount;
      if l_sum >= 7 then
        -- adjust the calculated amount using the last_sum value;
        -- so this row gets whatever is left from the 7, regardless
        -- of its actual value (but this must always be <= its amount)
        l_tab(j).calculated_amount := greatest(7 - l_last_sum, 0);
      end if;
      -- for use on the next inner loop
      l_last_sum := l_sum;
    end loop;

    -- send the current row with its final calculated amount
    pipe row (l_tab(i));
  end loop;
  return;
end;
/
```

With your test data:

```
select * from table(f42);

        ID     AMOUNT DT                  CALCULATED_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ------------------- -----------------
         1         .2 2010-01-01 18:42:00                .2 
         2         .4 2010-01-01 18:58:00                .4 
         3          3 2010-01-01 18:59:00                 3 
         4         .2 2010-01-01 19:00:00                .2 
         5         .2 2010-01-01 19:01:00                .2 
         6         .4 2010-01-01 19:02:00                .4 
         7        2.6 2010-01-01 19:04:00               2.6 
         8         .2 2010-01-01 19:05:00                .2 
         9       11.2 2010-01-01 19:06:00                 0 
        10       10.8 2010-01-01 19:08:00                 0 
        11       11.4 2010-01-01 19:09:00                .4 
        12        6.8 2010-01-01 19:18:00               6.6 
        13        1.8 2010-01-01 19:19:00                 0 
        14        1.6 2010-01-01 19:21:00                .4 
        15       11.4 2010-01-01 19:23:00                 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Alex. Your PL/SQL solution is very good. As you mentioned this will help someone else figure out a plain SQL approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your logic, however this query could be a starting point:

```
WITH test_data AS
   (         SELECT 1 ID , 0.2 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:42','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 ID , 0.4 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:58','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 ID , 3.0 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:59','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 ID , 0.2 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 5 ID , 0.2 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:01','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 6 ID , 0.4 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:02','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 ID , 2.6 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:04','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 8 ID , 0.2 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:05','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 9 ID , 11.2 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:06','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 10 ID , 10.8 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:08','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 11 ID , 11.4 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:09','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 12 ID , 6.8 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:18','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 13 ID , 1.8 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:19','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 14 ID , 1.6 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:21','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   UNION ALL SELECT 15 ID , 11.4 amount,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:23','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') dt FROM dual
   )
SELECT ID, amount, dt,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '10' MINUTE FOLLOWING) AS COUNT_ROWS_PER_10_MIN,
    SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY dt RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND INTERVAL '10' MINUTE FOLLOWING) AS SUM_PER_10_MIN
FROM test_data
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks your interest. I think the rule is clear (sum of amount can not be greater than 7 for any 10 minutes).

Comment: @Serkkan - that part of the rule is clear; the recursive part is not though.

Comment: Is there any suggestion?

Comment: I think looking at that screenshot makes me understand even less what you're trying to do >_<

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, which corresponds to the text of your description, but not the "expected result" you have.  Either way, I think it's close:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
   (         SELECT 1 ID , 0.2 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:42','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 2 ID , 0.4 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:58','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 3 ID , 3.0 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 18:59','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 4 ID , 0.2 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 5 ID , 0.2 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:01','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 6 ID , 0.4 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:02','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 7 ID , 2.6 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:04','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 8 ID , 0.2 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:05','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 9 ID , 11.2 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:06','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 10 ID , 10.8 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:08','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 11 ID , 11.4 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:09','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 12 ID , 6.8 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:18','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 13 ID , 1.8 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:19','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 14 ID , 1.6 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:21','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   UNION ALL SELECT 15 ID , 11.4 AMOUNT,TO_DATE('01.01.2010 19:23','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') DT FROM DUAL
   )
SELECT ID
    , SUM(AMOUNT)
    , SUM(CASE WHEN  NVL(FINAL_TOTAL, AMOUNT) != 0 THEN B_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS CALC
    , CASE
        WHEN SUM(AMOUNT) > 7 THEN 7 -   SUM(CASE WHEN  NVL(FINAL_TOTAL, AMOUNT) != 0 THEN B_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)
        ELSE SUM(AMOUNT)
       END AS ANSWER
FROM (
    SELECT A.ID
        , A.AMOUNT
        , A.DT
        , B.ID AS B_ID
        , NVL(B.AMOUNT, A.AMOUNT) AS B_AMOUNT
        , B.DT AS B_DT
        , SUM(B.AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY B.DT RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            CURRENT ROW) AS RUNNING_TOTAL
         , CASE 
            WHEN SUM(B.AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY B.DT RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            CURRENT ROW) > 7 THEN 0 ELSE
            SUM(B.AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY B.DT RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            CURRENT ROW) END AS FINAL_TOTAL
    FROM TEST_DATA A
    LEFT JOIN TEST_DATA B
          ON B.DT <= A.DT  + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
           AND B.DT >= A.DT
    ) X
WHERE NVL(FINAL_TOTAL, AMOUNT) != 0
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thanks your interest. I think it's close but we must use newly calculated values in previous steps.